# What properties can be plotted on an Ashby diagram?

Tags: materials

I am having trouble interpreting Ashby plots. Usually, I am given the plots with the shapes but I am asked to identify where each material (metal, ceramic, composite...) fits. Can someone provide me with a complete list of all the properties I must know of these basic materials in order to be able to fill in any usual Ashby plot?

Answer (score 2):

A google search shows that any two properties of interest (or more) can be plotted - based on work by Michael Ashby, so there are many answers possible.

See [material charts pdf](http://www.grantadesign.com/download/pdf/teaching_resource_books/2-Materials-Charts-2010.pdf)

One of several interesting or relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

All an Ashby Plot is, is a plot with one independent variable (X-axis) and two or three dependent variables.  One is plotted on the Y-axis, and the remaining identified by color, marker size, etc.  There's nothing special or unusual about this sort of graph.